# Get first Firestore document from an order of documents (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**What I want to do:** I want to get the first document from my collection in the Firestore, which should be order from Z-A when it comes to "description" in the document.

**The problem:** It tells me "No such document!". Although it should output me 1 document.

Here is the code:

```
getPost();

async function getPost() {

const postRef = db.collection('posts');
const doc = await postRef.orderBy('description', 'desc').limit(1).get()
.then(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error getting document', err);
});

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable `doc` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) object (**not** a DocumentSnapshot).  As you can see from the API documentation, it doesn't have a property called `exists`, so `if (!doc.exists)` will always be true.

Since a QuerySnapshot object always accounts for the possibility of containing more than one document (even if you specify `limit(1)`), you still have to check the size of its result set to know see how many documents you got.  You should probably do this instead:

```
const querySnapshot = await postRef.orderBy('description', 'desc').limit(1).get()
if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
    const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

Note also that there is no need to use then/catch if you are using await to capture the result of the query from the returned promise.